# SPM dependency between multiple packages

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, matlab-spm

I'm trying to create SPM hierarchy where some packages have dependecies on other, like this:
Package A is Core package where I also added dependencies to some external libraries and where I keep most of my native code:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Core",
    platforms: [
      .iOS(.v14)
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "Core",
            targets: ["Core"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
      .package(url: "https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit", .exact("6.13.1")),
      .package(url: "https://github.com/PromiseKit/Foundation.git", from: "3.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Core",
            dependencies: [
                           .product(name: "PMKFoundation", package: "Foundation"),
                           "PromiseKit",
                          ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "CoreTests",
            dependencies: ["Core"]),
    ]
)
```

Then I have package B, which has dependency on local package A, this package has only few classes but it should have access to external dependencies used by Core package:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Package_B",
    platforms: [
      .iOS(.v14)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Package_B",
            targets: ["Package_B"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
      .package(path: "../Core"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Package_B",
            dependencies: [
              "Core",
              "PromiseKit",
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "Package_BTests",
            dependencies: ["Package_B"]),
    ]
)
```

And Package C which has dependency on package B - it should has access to code from package B, to code from Core package and to external dependencies from Core package:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Package_C",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Package_C",
            targets: ["Package_C"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
      .package(path: "../Package_B"),
      .package(url: "https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive.git", from: "2.2.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Package_C",
            dependencies: ["Core","Package_B", "PromiseKit", "ZipArchive"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "Package_CTests",
            dependencies: ["Package_C"]),
    ]
)
```

Problem which I have is that for start Package_B is showing error in xcode:

```
x-xcode-log://7C2F67D1-F6A1-4BE1-8E94-DC7E769241AD product 'PromiseKit' required by package 'Package_B' target 'Package_B' not found.
```

I can add this line to Package_B dependency but it will not solve the issue:

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit", .exact("6.13.1")),
```

I can then try to compile the code but I got antoher errors like:

```
No such module 'PromiseKit'
No such module 'Core'
```

When I'm trying to Import those modules

Has anyone has some idea how to create a tree of dependecies between local packages which can be later used in multiple projects?

Comment: Just FYI you can create multiple modules using single Package.swift file

Comment: Have you tried by add public typealias for your external dependencies in your core module

Comment: I PackageB depends on PromiseKit, then it should provide info how to find it, so it's right that you have added it. If you getting message "No such module" then that module isn't compiled. Look for errors in the compilation logs.

Answer (score 0):

Package B must declare in its own dependencies and Package C must declare Core in its dependencies as well.

```
let package = Package(
name: "Package_B",
platforms: [
  .iOS(.v14)
],
products: [
    .library(
        name: "Package_B",
        targets: ["Package_B"]),
],
dependencies: [
  .package(path: "../Core"),
  .package(url: "https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit", .exact("6.13.1")),
  .package(url: "https://github.com/PromiseKit/Foundation.git", from: "3.0.0"),
],
],
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "Package_B",
        dependencies: [
          "Core",
          "PromiseKit",
        ]),
    .testTarget(
        name: "Package_BTests",
        dependencies: ["Package_B"]),
]
```

)

```
let package = Package(
name: "Package_C",
products: [
    .library(
        name: "Package_C",
        targets: ["Package_C"]),
],
dependencies: [
  .package(path: "../Core"),
  .package(path: "../Package_B"),
  .package(url: "https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive.git", from: "2.2.0"),
],
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "Package_C",
        dependencies: ["Core","Package_B", "PromiseKit", "ZipArchive"]),
    .testTarget(
        name: "Package_CTests",
        dependencies: ["Package_C"]),
]
```

)

Comment: Please, I have additional questions:
- I assume that the external packages (dependencies) will be embedded in whatever that uses these SPM packages. Let's assume it is a framework.
- However, there could be another framework in the app, that would also need to use PromiseKit, that is already a dependency of the first framework.
- How to avoid having the dependencies twice in the app (each framework having its copy)?
- OK, I could create another package depending on external PromiseKit, but then I need transitive dependency, and I was not successful in that at all. Any advice, please?